# TurtleBot Calibration -- Still waiting for scan

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following the turtlebot tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot)
I am stuck on 5.TurtleBot Odometry and Gyro Calibration

When I run 
$ roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch, 
I get the following output, and the final message "Still waiting for scan" repeats forever.

Any suggestions? 
I am using the full kit that comes with everything (irobot, kinect, eeepc, etc).

Thanks!

```
turtlebot@turtlepc:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/ff3cc802-d58c-11e0-8856-485d607f5c5a/roslaunch-turtlepc-13025.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11102/turtlebot-calibration----still-waiting-for-scan/) by [C](https://answers.ros.org/users/1032/c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like your TurtleBot software on your TurtleBot might not be up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-turtlebot-robot
```

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [C](https://answers.ros.org/users/1032/c/) on 2011-09-02**:
Thanks! That helped a bit. It now gets past the previous error, and the robot starts rotating. However, before completing a full turn, it stops and the wrench icon on the dashboard becomes red. Its says Power System: Error.